# Bluetooth 4.0 LE for GPS

Tags: ios, gps, tracking, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am looking for a **gps tracker using bluetooth low energy** (so there's no need for mfi-programm. using apple devices).
Is it even possible, since BTLE saves energy and gps-tracking requires a more or less constant connection?

I'm thankful for any informations I can get about BTLE + GPS

Greetings
Timm

Comment: First try out your self and if stuck then ask the question so we can have little thing to answer not everything .

Comment: well, as mentioned i'm looking for a gps tracker using btle, so how should i try anything? 
however, if someone can give me the information that it's not even possible, then i wont find a gps tracker with btle.

Comment: im aware of this solution: http://blutracker.com/
But it's a locator, not a tracker

Comment: why do you need external bT tracker? iphones have a superior GPS built in.

Comment: i want to track in 10hz

Answer (score -1):

I know no equivalent on iOS platform - but on Android platform - use SmartNAVI to broadcast mock GPS location using the phone sensors (starting from a know location) as a replacement GPS (so GPS does not need to be on) - then feed this into an app called BlueScan - which logs BTLE device RSSI based on there GPS location and time. - I wish there were something equivalent on iOS - but alas iOS is seriously behind in the world of engineering development/IT platform when it comes to the world of IoT, BTLE, etc.